# Where I can find a torsional stiffness table for different types of stainless steels?

Tags: resource-recommendations, material-science, torque, stress-strain

I am trying to comparing the torsional stiffness of different types of stainless steels. I googled the keywords but I could not find any useful information. Would anyone please give me some links which provide those information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stiffness, linear or torsional does not depend on the particular alloy, but only on the base material. For your case you want the shear modulus used in

$$\theta = \frac{T\, \ell}{G\, J}$$

Here $T$ is the torque, $\ell$ the length, $J=I_{xx}+I_{yy}$ is the polar moment of area and $G$ is the shear modulus. This can be defined as $G = \frac{E}{2(1+\nu)}$ from the [modulus of elasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) $E$ and Poisson's ratio $\nu$.

You can find some values [here](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/modulus-rigidity-d_946.html) for modulus of rigidity.

Turning the equation around you have the torsional stiffness $$\frac{{\rm d} T}{{\rm d}\theta} = \frac{G\,J}{\ell}$$

Comment: Dear @ja72: Do you have a reference for your first sentence? I believe you, but to me it sounds very interesting because I would not have foreseen such an idea. Is it then true to say that it is the nonlinear properties like yield stress and ultimate tensile strength are those affected by alloying - it makes a bit more sense then.

Comment: When you use energy methods to find force displacement, or moment angle relationships the resulting stiffness is always proportional to a combination of of $E$ and $\nu$ or $G$ and $\nu$. Factors that might affect $E$ is temperature, work hardening and porosity.

Comment: Very interesting. I'd never have known - thanks - this is a great site for learning.

Comment: So a chrome vanadium steel would have the same "stiffness" as pure iron ??   I never would have believed it, if I hadn't read it here.

Comment: @GeorgeE.Smith, no not the same. Steel is different from Iron. Carbon Steel $G=77\,{\rm GPa}$ and Iron $G=65\,{\rm GPa}$ Did look at http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/modulus-rigidity-d_946.html ?

Comment: What I mean by different alloys, is 302 vs 304 vs 316 stainless steel. All of those would have the same modulus of rigidity $G$.

Comment: So I thought I understood English, fairly well, so what exactly does this mean:    """"....Stiffness, linear or torsional does not depend on the particular alloy, but only on the base material. ...."""""    Is not iron, the base material in the two "alloys" that I mentioned.   So what about a 416 stainless steel, versus the three you mentioned; and what about the heat treatment  differences ?   Just what set of conditions are required for your statement to be valid  ??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloy